# Создание структуры проекта в автоматическом режиме

Tags: project

Приветствую.
Занимаюсь вёрсткой. У каждого нового проекта, скелет или структура примерно одинаковая. Что я имею ввиду? Папки , некоторые файлы, импорты в .sass файлы.
Каждый раз приходится создавать всё вручную или copy-paste,хотелось бы автоматизировать создание нужной структуры путем ввода одной команды. Приведу самый банальный пример структуры

```
Project_folder
  css
    styles.css
  js
    script.js
  images
    img_1.png
  index.html
```

Кто чем пользуется? Что можете посоветовать? Благодарю всех откликнувшихся.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто сделайте шаблон проекта для используемой вами IDE. Это не так уж сложно - достаточно пары щелчков.

Ссылки на соответствующую документацию для различных IDE:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xkh1wxd8.aspx - Visual Studio
- https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/saving-projects-as-templates.html - IDE компании JetBrains(IDEA, WebStorm, RubyMine, PHPStorm, PyCharm)
- https://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-projectsamples.html - NetBeans